# Css file not getting properly read in jquery script

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css

I created a dropdown box which will help wrap long texts in the box. Now, when i use that control in a separate solution, it reads the .css file properly and all the style, font, alignment is proper. But if i integrate it with my application, none of the formatting read from the .css file works. Am not sure how to debug this stuff too. Do suggest some solution where i could at least figure out why the .css file is not working when i integrate it with my application.

Thanks in advance,
Geetha

---

Please refer the source code in the link given below...

http://www.scottdarby.com/plugins/stylish-select/0.3/

It is exactly the same dropdown that am trying to integrate with my application.

Thanks,
Geetha

---

And the challenge here is, i have to get the dropdown done in IE6.. Is there any possibility to debug it in IE 6?? Please let me know!

Thanks,
Geetha

Comment: can you provide some code examples, or a link to the page?

Answer (score 1):

Is the CSS file loaded by the page?

If you're using Firefox, take a look at [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com), which has some great tools for checking the actual rendered HTML and CSS of a page, after javascript has run.

If you're using IE, version 8 has Developer Tools (similar to FireBug and the old IE 7 Developer Toolbar) which can be accessed by pressing F12, or on the menu bar, otherwise, you can get the [IE7 Developer Toolbar from Microsoft here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en).

Using either of these tools will help you see what's actually going on with your html and css.

Comment: Firefox + Firebug is the key for html/ccs/javascript debugging. If you haven't installed it, do it now.